# How to get a form element that has a dynamic ID - Need to get the element with the highest ID

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with check boxes that are populated dynamically resulting in something like the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="1-subject" value="Option A" class="check" id="id_1-subject_0">
<input type="checkbox" name="1-subject" value="Option B" class="check" id="id_1-subject_1">
<input type="checkbox" name="1-subject" value="Other:" class="check" id="id_1-subject_2">

<input type="text" name="1-subject_other" id="id_1-subject_other" class="text" onkeyup="Test();" >
```

If I need the "Other:" checkbox to be automatically checked if anything is typed in the text field I could do this:

```
<script>
function Test(){
    var a = document.getElementById("id_1-subject_other");
    var b = document.getElementById("id_1-subject_2");
    if (!a) {
        b.checked=true;
    }
}
</script>
```

However if another option is added, the 'Other:' checkbox will change to id_1-subject_3. How would I get this field by the dynamically changing ID as var b? Or can I get by value of 'Other:'?

Comment: Should be `if (!a.checked) {...`. right?

Comment: var a is the text field. so if var a is not blank then check var b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the value of the "Other:" input will not change, you can use:

`document.querySelector('input[value="Other:"]')`

and get the element.

Comment: Why not `document.querySelector('input[value="Other:"]')`, which saves you from having to scan the whole DOM, create a node list and then extract the one and only thing out of the node list?

Answer (score 0):

You can get [dom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/DOM) using [`document.querySelector('input[name=other]')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) on `keyup` event.

> The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

**DEMO**

```js
function Test(el){
  document.querySelector('input[name=other]').checked= el.value!='';
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="1-subject" value="Option A" class="check" id="id_1-subject_0"><label>A</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="1-subject" value="Option B" class="check" id="id_1-subject_1"><label>B</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="other" value="Other:" class="check" id="id_1-subject_2"><label>Other</label><br>

<input type="text" name="1-subject_other" id="id_1-subject_other" class="text" onkeyup="Test(this);">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jQuery by value.

```
$("input[type=checkbox][value='Other:']").prop("checked",true);
```